# Google Search Console says it crawled the website but the access logs show no google Bots access at all

Tags: googlebot

Google Search Console tells me that it crawled the website last today (I requested a fresh crawling, as the last was some months ago.)

The crawling report tells me now it crawled it, last, today.

However, the server access logs show nothing related to google bots. I can see al kind of bots, linkdexbot, ZoominfoBot, etc etc, but no Googlebot at all

What am I missing?
Is google not using any detectable bot anymore or are their reports false?

Comment: Googlebot shows up in access logs. Check again. Can it be a timezone issue? (Between server time and search console timezones)

Comment: I am sure it is not there, cmd+f "Googlebot" returns no results - and timezone couldn't affect that, really, since the log is from today + yesterday (+48 hours)...

Comment: My bad! NOW it is there - still weird since google stated to have crawled some hours ago though the logs are only telling it now. However, this part is solved. Thanks @kannan.